# Most pythonic way to find relation between two elements in a list

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have the following list:

```
l = ["watermelon", "banana", "orange", "apple"]
```

And I want to write a function that returns whatever the element is before another element in the list. for example:

```
>> is_before("banana", "watermelon")
>> False
>> is_before("banana", "apple")
>> True
```

What is the most pythonic way to write such a function?

Comment: Is previous or is before?

Comment: tom-ato toma-to?

Comment: Nope, banana is before apple, but is not the previous element

Comment: uh ok, so before, not necessarily previous

Comment: OK, so please edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Do you need to handle duplicates?

Answer (score 3):

You could do (assuming there are no duplicates):

```
l = ["watermelon", "banana", "orange", "apple"]

indeces = {w: i for i, w in enumerate(l)}

def is_previous(x, y):
    return indeces[x] < indeces[y]

>>> is_previous("banana", "watermelon")
False
>>> is_previous("banana", "apple")
True
```

This does not handle the case where any of the arguments aren't in the initial list.

Comment: loved the approach. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps if you iterate backwards, this could handle duplicates. In the end the only thing that matters is the firs appearance of each element

Comment: @schwobaseggl  Good and easy approach but if there is duplicate values in the given list then just like Dani Mesejo said you need to iterate backwards,

Comment: The OP does not state what the expected output would be in that case. What if "apple" occurs before *and* after "banana"? Should it be `True` or `False`, the behavoiur with duplicates is entirely unclear. Nowhere does the OP mention first occurrence.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Yup, you are right he didn't mention that case (+1).

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist = ["watermelon", "banana", "orange", "apple"]

def is_before(prev_item, target, arr):
    return prev_item in arr[:arr.index(target)]

>>>is_before("banana", "apple", mylist)
True
>>>is_before("banana", "watermelon", mylist)
False
```

If you want to handle duplicates you can use something like this

```
def find_item_last_index(count, item, arr, index=0):
    # A recursive function for finding the last index of an item in a list
    if count == 1:
        return index + arr.index(item)
    return (find_item_last_index(count-1, item, arr[arr.index(item)+1:],  
                                 index+arr.index(item)+1))

def is_before(prev_item, target, arr):
    return prev_item in arr[: find_item_last_index(arr.count(target), target, arr)]

mylist =  ["watermelon", "apple", "banana", "orange", "apple"]

>>>is_before("banana", "apple", mylist)
True
>>>is_before("banana", "watermelon", mylist)
False
```